# AngularJS - ngClick is blocking submit key action

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

The user of my web should enter a simple code using buttons in my form and after that he should click `Ok` or hit enter and continue with proccess.

The thing is that the *enter* key is not submiting my form, is executing other method that is called from `ng-click`. How can avoid enter key call the ng-click method?

**myapp.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('myformcontroller', ['$scope', function ($scope){
    // Procesing data from form.
    $scope.signin = function () {
    }
}]);

myApp.controller('mycontroller', ['$scope', function ($scope){
   $scope.do = function() {
       alert('ng-click pressed!');
   }
}]);
```

**myform.html**

```
<div ng-controller="myformcontroller">

    <form name="myForm"
          role="form" 
          ng-submit="signin()" 
          novalidate>

        <input type="text"/>

        <div ng-controller="mycontroller">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="do()">
                clickme!
            </a>
        </div>

        <button type="submit">Ok</button>
    </form>

</div>
```

Press `click me` and hit `enter` key after on [My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/napstercake/HB7LU/15276/)

Comment: that doesn't make any sense; `ng-click` doesn't change an `<a>` into a `<button>`; the symptoms you are describing don't seem like they could occur with the sample you are showing here.

Comment: No it's not an issue

Comment: looks more like a scope problem, form is under different controller scope than the `<a>` tag. WHy is there a different controller inside the form? WHere is the controller for the form?

Comment: Because the do() method is showing simple messages to the user before the form is submitted. And I'm dealing with an mandatory app structure on my project.

Comment: Seems to me that because they are clicking the link, that element has focus. Maybe at the end of the do() function add some jQuery to change the page focus: $('#submit').focus();

Comment: could use a span or something that doesn't take focus like an `<a>` does. If you change to span issue dissappears. Might need to add some aria attributes if accessibility is important

Comment: @charlietfl that solved my problem. I'm still not getting my form submited with the enter key but I think it is easy to solved.

Comment: likely because you have nothing within form that takes focus

Comment: @charlietfl you are right! sorry for that, I'm very blocked right now. Thanks for everything!

Answer (score 0):

It is not blocking. You're missing a standard input to bubble the properly handled click event. If there is no input, the form is not submitted by default. It's not an angular issue. Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/477699/4573999

**EDIT**
More detailed explanation based on comments. The question is not about the submit element. Sure, you have a button type submit. The for other elements inside the form there is a default behavior. And for `input` element the default on `enter` key is to submit the form that it is surrounded by. But for the anchor tag it is not. Because it is not supposed to provide any data. Why would you want to submit a form on a link? So in your case you should submit the form programmatically by calling appropriate method.

```
myApp.controller('myformcontroller', ['$scope', function ($scope){
    $scope.signin = function () {
               alert('submit!');
    }
}]);

myApp.controller('mycontroller', ['$scope', function ($scope){
   $scope.do = function() {
       alert('ng-click pressed!');
       $scope.signin();
   }
}]);
```

Check updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/15285/)
If you'd like to get this in a generic way, you can parse the `ng-submit` value like here [How to programmatically submit a form with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23813413/how-to-programmatically-submit-a-form-with-angularjs)

Comment: not true, button will do the same as long as it is type=submit which is default of no type is set

Comment: Same result changing my button to input with submit type. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can ommit html rules with jquery. 
Add id to a form and button first:

```
<form id="mydiv" name="myForm"
    role="form" 
    ng-submit="signin()" 
    novalidate>

    <div ng-controller="mycontroller">
       <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="do()">
          <img src="img/a-letter.png" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>

    <button id="mydiv2" type="submit">Ok</button>
</form>
```

And then set listener on enter up:

```
$("#mydiv").keyup(function(event){
if(event.keyCode == 13){
    $("#mydiv2").click();
}
});
```

So it's not elegant, but you can submit form with simulating click on enter pressed.